# css of nested div not working

Tags: html, css

i dont understand why this not working, i have this situation:

```
<div class="x" id="1">
    <div class="x" id="2">
        <div class="x" id="3">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css file:

```
<style>
#1{display:block; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:blue}
#2{display:block; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:red}
#3{display:block; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:green}
</style>
```

Why when i load the page, the css rule doesnt apply? Am i missing something? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ID cannot start with a digit.  Use a letter instead.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) says that an id selector cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

[id names cannot begin with numbers.](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

[Although HTML5 appears to allow it](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), it doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Both people are correct. But, I believe you need to put content in the divs to see the rules apply.

Comment: For what? Needing content?

Comment: He has the height and width set on the elements which will give those elements the needed sizing which does what he wants to do. Content is not needed to make a visible element when the elements have sizes applied.